# "Perfino" e "persino" si usano sempre ugualmente?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adverbs

Forse questa domanda vi sembrerà troppo semplice. Tenete conto però che, per qualcuno che non ha mai abitato in Italia, non è tutto così evidente.

Vorrei sapere se i vocaboli "perfino" e "persino" si usano sempre ugualmente. Cioè, c'è alcuna situazione in cui è preferibile usare uno o l'altro? Esiste qualche differenza regionale di uso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sono perfettamente intercambiabili, come suggerisce il dizionario Treccani.

[Persino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/persino/):

> - persino avv. [comp. di per-, con valore rafforzativo, e sino]. – **Lo stesso che perfino (v.), con cui si alterna nell’uso.**

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perfino%2Cpersino&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperfino%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersino%3B%2Cc0) *persino  e  perfino*  sono comunemente usati senza particolare preferenza per l'uno o per l'altro.

Vale la pena notare che sia come avverbio che  preposizione  *sino* è meno comune e un po'  più  formale rispetto a  *fino*. Lo stesso vale per i termini composti ad eccezione dei *perfino e persino* come notato sopra:

> - [Sino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sino/) :
> - prep. e avv. [alteraz. di fino, prob. per incrocio con il lat. sic]. – Variante di fino, prep. e avv., nei suoi varî sign.: sino a ieri, sin qui, sin d’ora, sino da Milano; ha impegnato sino la camicia. *È meno com. di fino, e in genere di tono più elevato; a volte la preferenza per l’una o per l’altra forma è suggerita da ragioni di eufonia (sino a Firenze, ma fin sopra i capelli).*
> - Analogam. per i composti sinora, insino, persino e i meno com. sinché, sintantoché, sinattantoché, varianti di finora, infino, perfino, finché, ecc.

Comment: Occhio, che il link è ai dati del corpus inglese. [Quello italiano](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=persino%2Cperfino&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersino%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperfino%3B%2Cc0), per quel che vale, mostra una lieve prevalenza di “perfino” sino al 1970, dopodiché passerebbe avanti “persino”.

Comment: Comunque confermo che anche lo Zingarelli, per “persino”, rimanda a “perfino”.

Comment: @DaG - ho modificato Ngram, grazie. Direi che la sostanza non cambia.

Comment: Sì, penso anch'io.

Comment: Sebbene siano intercambiali, in determinati contesti uno suona meglio dell'altro ma non saprei dire perché...

Comment: @black: Potresti fare alcuni esempi?

Comment: @Charo Non so dirti, mi spiace. *Suppongo* che, essendo "persino" più datato, con alcune parole suoni meglio perché legato ad esse da più tempo di "perfino".